# How should I play against the Alekhine?

Tags: opening, analysis, alekhines-defense

I like to play the variation below, although it may seem a little bit awkward.

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 Nf6 2. e5 Nd5 3. c4 Nb6 4. c5 Nd5
```

From here you can play `Nc3` or `Bc4`. White will have a lot of space and if the black player is going to play it wrong, he will have a disadvantage for the complete game.

Comment: The question at current time is: "What do you play against the Alekhine?". This question should be rephrased somehow. For example: What is a good (or aggressive or tricky) opening against the Alekhine?  As the question stands now it is more of a social question and no answer will ever be wrong or better than another answer.  If not changed I would vote to close it.

Comment: I chose to read it as "What does one play against the Alekhine?".

Comment: @dfan I understood it as that too, but it would not hurt to change it either.  I thought it would be reasonable to let him have a chance to change it himself.  I did not down vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.c4 Nb6 4.c5 Nd5 is known as the Chase Variation and is playable, though not considered to be particularly great for White.

At the highest levels, the most popular variation for White is the Modern Variation, 1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.d4 d6 4.Nf3. However, Black is left with a lot of freedom about how to continue, so White needs to be ready to handle a lot of continuations.

At club level the most common continuation seems to be the Exchange Variation, 1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.d4 d6 4.c4 Nb6 5.exd6 (note that moves 3 and 4 are often reversed). Play proceeds differently depending on how Black recaptures the pawn.

The most aggressive (and most principled) choice for White is the Four Pawns Attack, 1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.d4 d6 4.c4 Nb6 5.f4. White stakes out a ton of space but has to prove that he hasn't become overextended. Play often becomes very tactical.

Answer (score 5):

I usually play the [Saemisch Attack](http://chessopenings.com/eco/B02/10/) ...

**1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.Nc3**

```
[Title "Saemisch Attack to Alekhine's Defense"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "5"]

1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.Nc3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can play a sort of system in the Alekhine against most black (reasonable) moves, its called the Voronezh system if I am not mistaken.
It arises after the Exchange Variation, 1.e4 Nf6 2.e5 Nd5 3.d4 d6 4.c4 Nb6 5.exd6

And now regardless of which capture is used by black, white should proceed with Nc3-Be3-Rc1-b3 unless black plays some very provocative move.
This system has the advantage of nullifying the fianchettoed DSB so common in the Alekhine and giving you a pleasant position as white